# Testing for intersection between two arcs

Tags: javascript, math

I have two arcs, defined by objects containing their start and end angles, their centres, and their radii.

The definition looks something like this:

```
arc = {
    start: 0,
    end: Math.PI,
    radius: 10,
    centre: [0, 0]
}
```

I want to know if the arcs intersect at any point, but I'm unsure how to do this. I've tried finding points of intersection between the two circles with the same radii and centres of the arcs, and then checking if those points are on both arcs, but this is complicated by the fact that my start/end angles might not be between 0 and 2π - they could be any value, and I'm not sure how to check whether the circle intersections lie on the arcs.

How can I check whether two arcs intersect? (For what it's worth, I'm using JavaScript, but any language would work as an answer)

Comment: Maybe you could use a %2pi (module operator) to always get the angles between 0 and 2pi

Comment: I'm unsure if that works directly. For example, the arc between (2π-0.1) and (2π+0.1) covers the angle 0, but if I get the modulus of that by 2π, then I get the arc between 0.1 and (2π-0.1), which _doesn't_ cover 0.

Comment: Will the following always be true for your arc: `Math.abs(arc.start - arc.end) <= Math.PI`?

Comment: Or better: `arc.end - arc.start <= 2* Math.PI`? Sorry, I meant `2*Math.PI` in the previous comment as well

Comment: Unfortunately not. Arcs could be greater than a whole circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a bit old but needs an answer. But first, the arc structure does not have enough information to work with the question the way it was stated. There is nothing that tells if the arc goes around more than 2pi radians and how many times around. If it did, the idea of an arc of more than 2pi is geometrically absurd anyhow, and the possibility needs to be avoided. If you want to write a lot of code to handle non-geometric concepts here, that's beyond what I'll address and it's up to you to include more data in the structure and to test it properly. There is also nothing that tells us if the arc is defined as always being clockwise, counterclockwise. But the problem is easy to solve if the direction is well defined. For now, let's make the assumption that zero length arcs are never used and that arcs never go around more than 2pi radians. Let's also assume that arcs are always defined clockwise.

Now it's easy. Get up to two points that are the intersections of the two circles that the two arcs are on. Repeat the analysis for both points...

Get the angle of an intersection point. If an arc start angle is less than the end angle then just test to see if the intersection angle is at or between those two angles. But if the start angle is greater than the end angle of the arc then do two tests, one to see if the intersection angle is at or above the start angle and also at or below 2pi radians and also test, if needed, to see if the intersection angle is at or above zero and at or below the end angle of the arc.

I think that pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
on_arc = false;
if( start > end )
{
    if( intersect >= start && intersect <= 2pi )
        on_arc = true;
    else if( intersect >= 0 && intersect <= end )
        on_arc = true;
}
else if( start == end )
    on_arc = true; // arc is the entire circle since we are not handling zero length arcs.
else
{
    if( intersect >= start && intersect <= end )
        on_arc = true;
}
```

If there is a flag in the arc structure to tell if the arc is clockwise or counterclockwise then the code could simply swap start and end angles before the tests.

Just avoid the >2pi arc idea because it's not useful. Whatever calculates the arc is either some sort of geometric 2D concept or it's something that can have a 2pi limit.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simpler case.  How do you test for intersection of two circles.  Two circles are going to intersect in zero places (too far apart), exactly one ( just touching ), two places ( overlapping ), or everywhere ( centers and radius are equal ).

Figure out how to calculate the one or two places circles would overlap, then figure out if either point is contained within both arcs.

For the last part, I would normalize the range so that `start` is between `(-pi, pi]` (the same return range as `atan2()`).

```
while ( start > M_PI ) { start -= 2 * M_PI, end -= 2 * M_PI ; }
```

Then use `atan2()` to find the angle that the point of intersection falls within the circle, and test that it is between `start` and `end`.

If you can get that to work, and want to improve performance further, there are ways using cross product to do a similar test without the trig calculations, but they require a certain number of special cases.

Comment: I've said that I've tried this already, in my question. I'm unsure how to do the latter bit - "figure out if either point is contained within both arcs".

Comment: Look into turning the point of intersection on the circle to an angle using `atan2`.